# Can spinnaker use local storage such as mysql database?

Tags: spinnaker

I want to deploy spinnaker for my team. But I encounter a problem. The document of spinnaker said:

> Before you can deploy Spinnaker, you must configure it to use one of the supported storage types.
>
> - Azure Storage
> - Google Cloud Storage
> - Redis
> - S3

Can spinnaker use local storage such as mysql database?

Answer (score 3):

The Spinnaker microservice responsible for persisting your pipeline configs and application metadata, front50, has support for the storage systems you listed. One could add support for additional systems like mysql by extending front50, but that support does not exist today.

Some folks have had success configuring front50 to use s3 and pointing it at a minio installation.